# Wordpress css issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi I am working on wordpress stuff, not sure whats wrong with the code, pasting the code snippet.First 2 sections are fine but the third section is coming on top please see the attached image for reference. Any help is appreciated.

```
[vc_section full_width="stretch_row" parallax="content-moving" parallax_speed_bg="1" css=".vc_custom_1499842858246{padding-top: 45px !important;padding-bottom: 45px !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}"][vc_row][vc_column][vc_custom_heading text="HELP THE HOMELESS PEOPLE" font_container="tag:div|text_align:center|color:%23555555" use_theme_fonts="yes" css=".vc_custom_1500283712583{margin-top: 10px !important;}"][vc_custom_heading text="ALONE SHOP PRODUCTS" font_container="tag:h2|font_size:40px|text_align:center|line_height:45px" use_theme_fonts="yes" custom_letter_spacing="-2px" css=".vc_custom_1500275688528{margin-top: 0px !important;margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"][vc_custom_heading text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam," font_container="tag:p|text_align:center" use_theme_fonts="yes" css=".vc_custom_1499843029941{margin-top: 10px !important;margin-bottom: 35px !important;}"][/vc_column][/vc_row]

[vc_row][vc_column width="1/3"]


[vc_featured_box heading_text="Donation" content_text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam" heading_color="#222222" content_color="#444444" graphic="image" graphic_size="100" show_button="show" button_text="JOIN NOW" button_type="circle" image="291"]

[/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3"]

[vc_featured_box heading_text="Volunteers" content_text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam" heading_color="#222222" content_color="#444444" graphic="image" graphic_size="100" show_button="show" button_text="JOIN NOW" button_type="circle" image="291"]

[/vc_column][vc_column width="1/3"][vc_featured_box heading_text="Fundraising" content_text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam" heading_color="#222222" content_color="#444444" graphic="image" graphic_size="100" show_button="show" button_text="JOIN NOW" button_type="circle" image="291"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### try to make duplicate column and check if its working fine or not. If works then its issue of vc or if still not come properly then its an issue of your theme. In this case add some id to div and set style for that section.

your theme is working fine here.
[image]

Comment: I tried that but same issue, not sure why it it happening.

Comment: is it possible to get the url, so i can check it from my end?

Comment: If you see carefully its not, donation is not inclined to other two sections.